# Error getting the constant mac address of an android device via the WifiManager

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the MacAdress of an android device using Java through WifiManager

```
  public String getMacAdress(Context context){
    WifiManager wifiManager=(WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    String macAdress=wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
    if(macAdress==null){
        macAdress="Device don't have mac address or wi-fi is disabled";
    }
    return  macAdress;
}
```

but it's returning the constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.
And I set the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: What else do you expect? Are you running the code on a real device or an emulator?

Comment: Nothing wrong with you code.You getting this `02:00:00:00:00:00.` in emulator?

Comment: I'm running on a real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API 23, `getMacAddress()` returns a constant value, and not the actual MAC address. This is for security and privacy purposes. If you have older devices, you will get the actual MAC address, provided those devices are within your `minSdkVersion` to `targetSdkVersion` range

Answer (score 0):

Beginning Android 6.0 or above API will give you MAC address is 02:00:00:00:00:00. Refer below:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html

> **Access to Hardware Identifier** To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic
>   access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the
>   Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs.
>
> The **WifiInfo.getMacAddress()** and the
>   **BluetoothAdapter.getAddress()** methods now return a constant value of **02:00:00:00:00:00**.

Try this code:

```
public String getMacAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> ifaceList = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface iface : ifaceList) {
            if (iface == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!iface.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) {
                continue;
            }
            byte[] macBytes = iface.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }
            StringBuilder macSb = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte bytes : macBytes) {
                macSb.append(String.format("%02X:", bytes));
            }
            if (macSb.length() == 0) {
                return "";
            }
            macSb.deleteCharAt(macSb.length() - 1);
            return macSb.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```